# React Hooks: Best practise in passing state between children of hook component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to access an object set to a child component's state, and pass it to its sibling component:

- Child 1 (TextDetection) is a [react-dropzone component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone) that receives an image file, which is passed to an OCR API.
- Child 1 will then receive the transcription from the API and set that returned transcription to its local state.
- Child 2 (TextTable) needs to access this same object, where it will be displayed.

### Child 1

```
function TextDetection({ textToParent }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const uploadImage = async (image) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', image[0])
    const response = await fetch('/upload', {
      method: "post",
      body: formData
    })
    const body = await response.json();
    setData(body.split(/\r?\n/))
    textToParent(data)
  }

  return (
    <Grid container className="App" direction="column" alignItems="stretch">
      <Container id="dropzoneContainer">
        <Card variant="outlined">
          <Dropzone uploadImage = {uploadImage}/>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

The intention is the make this transcription available to the sibling component. As you can see in the snippet below, I am currently accessing the child's state by passing a callback to it via props.

### Parent

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState([])

  function handleChange(newText) {
    setText(newText)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
        <TextDetection textToParent={handleChange}/>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
        <TextTable segments={text}/>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Passing a callback to a child to access its state doesn't align with the concept of [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).
Is there a means of applying that principle in this case, given that the TextDetection child is receives the object set to state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextDetection` component should handle everything related to OCR, which includes parsing the text. However, it shouldn't have a local state. When done parsing it should call `textToParent`.

```
function TextDetection({ textToParent }) {
  const uploadImage = async (image) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', image[0])
    const response = await fetch('/upload', {
      method: "post",
      body: formData
    })
    const body = await response.json();
    textToParent(body.split(/\r?\n/));
  }

  return (
    <Grid container className="App" direction="column" alignItems="stretch">
      <Container id="dropzoneContainer">
        <Card variant="outlined">
          <Dropzone uploadImage = {uploadImage}/>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

The parent should hold the state created by `TextDetection, and supply it to the` TextTable` (and any other child that needs it).

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState([])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
        <TextDetection textToParent={setText}/>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
        <TextTable segments={text}/>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the solution. Keeping the handler function in the child makes complete sense, so I've marked this as the correct answer.

Comment: You're welcome. This falls under separation of concerns - one should OCR, the other should display the result (the text), and one should orchestrate. The orchestrator should hold the state.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you don't use `data` in Child component at all. In this case you can run function in Parent component

```
function TextDetection({ textToParent }) {
  return (
    <Grid container className="App" direction="column" alignItems="stretch">
      <Container id="dropzoneContainer">
        <Card variant="outlined">
          <Dropzone uploadImage = {textToParent}/>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Parent:

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState([])

  function handleChange(newText) {
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('photo', image[0])
     const response = await fetch('/upload', {
        method: "post",
        body: formData
     })
     const body = await response.json();
     setText(body.split(/\r?\n/))
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
        <TextDetection textToParent={handleChange}/>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
        <TextTable segments={text}/>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: This is concept, not tested.

Comment: Thank you for such a speedy reply! The change makes total sense (I feel silly for not having thought of it myself!), however I've marked the other answer as the correct one because it keeps the reference to the endpoint within the component the makes the request.